# What is the community mailbox?

Tags: support, closed-questions, revisions-list

What is the community mailbox (community@stackexchange.com) for and what happens to messages that are sent to it?

Additionally, on some closed questions that have lots of views, I see the following message in the revision history just when the question is closed:

> occurred sometime *(right justified in actual)*
>
> **A notice was sent to community@stackexchange.com about a popular question being closed.**

What is the criteria for a question being "popular" enough for such a message to be sent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm Grace Note, a Community Manager here at Stack Exchange.

community@ is one of many email addresses that we, the Stack Exchange staff, use for different forms of alerts and notifications. If you want to reach us please use our [contact us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) form, located at the bottom of any page on our network, to ensure that it comes to us properly.

As far as the criteria for the notice being sent on closed questions...the exact criteria aren't all that important; "popular" captures the goal. These notices are just a mechanism for the community managers to be aware of potentially controversial or attention-getting closures on the network, since these often crop up as discussions here on meta and may require a response from the team.